# Youtube insterted video not showing full screen button when accessed through iframe in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, youtube, fullscreen

I'm unsure as to why I'm unable to see the full screen button when viewing an embedded youtube video through an iframe in chrome. This only occurs in chrome (tested with Firefox, IE, Safari, Chrome).

You can see what I mean with the below fiddle as it renders through an iframe.
    `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/BKorP55Aqvg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

http://jsfiddle.net/9sgng/

Is this a bug/google preference or is there a way around it?

Comment: facing the same issue both in chrome and IE

Comment: Hey @mjs, I worked out that I only had allowfullscreen on the youtube iframe; you also need it on the iframe that is holding the youtube iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out that I only had allowfullscreen on the youtube iframe, but you also need it on the iframe that is holding the youtube iframe.

Comment: If `iframeNode` holds a reference to a superordinate iframe element, you can set it with `iframeNode.setAttribute('allowfullscreen','true');`